# Creating a C++ win32 program from scratch

Tags: c++, windows, win32gui

There isn't any books in my library on XAML only C++. I want to know if there's a way to make a Win32 program in C++ 64 bit without dealing with XAML and Visual Studio. I want to only use Windows Notepad. Where do I start?

Comment: You start by searching the Internet, because there are many thousands of WIN32 examples and tutorials all over the place. Once you feel ready to start programming, get a better editor. notepad is *lousy* for programming. There are many good (and free) text editors geared towards programming. Then of course you need a compiler, and here too there are a few alternatives (including using the Visual Studio compiler, it's freely available with Visual Studio Express editions after all).

Comment: I don't see any tutorials that allow me to use only Windows Notepad. For a compiler I wonder if there's an official C++ compiler.

Comment: You don't have to search for tutorials that teach you how to do a windows program with notepad, you need to search for tutorials that teach you how to do a windows program and stop!

Comment: I want the official C++ compiler and the official win32 header file

Comment: Searching for ***win32 tutorial*** gave me [this Microsoft Developer Network link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384843.aspx) at the top. It shows a complete WIN32 program. Disregard the project/IDE stuff, and follow the *code*.

Comment: Search for it then. Google is your friend

Comment: Where do I download the official Win32 header file, windows.h?

Comment: All you need to program C++ in, on and for Windows you can get for free from Microsoft. You really need to tune up your searching skills. Hint: One thing that you should search for is a *Software Development Kit*, a.k.a. a *SDK*.

Comment: But the SDK is only for Visual Studio. I only want to download the compiler and header files.

Comment: Search what you need to do to start. Don't make other people do what you can do by yourself

Comment: Are you searching for `XAML only C++` or for something `without dealing with XAML and Visual Studio`? Please make clear what you want, with or without.

Comment: All I want to know is where I can download the official C++ compiler and the windows.h header file

Comment: I found a C++ compiler, Clang, from the official C++ website, https://isocpp.org/get-started. Now all I need to know is where to download the file windows.h.

Comment: @EphraimBecker: As you were told several times now, you get `windows.h` from Microsoft.  You need to download the Windows SDK from Microsoft (unless your compiler includes its own copy of the SDK). `windows.h` is part of the Windows SDK. And `windows.h` is not a standalone file, anyway. It has dependencies on many other files in the SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it! The windows.h file is in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Include and I downloaded the C++ compiler, Clang.

Comment: There is no "official C++ compiler".  You can also download MinGW and Cygwin/GCC.  There are also free downloads for Visual Studio.

Comment: Like Thomas said, there is no "official" C++ compiler for Windows development. VisualC++ is **Microsoft's** official compiler (and you can get it for free from Microsoft), but there are MANY third-party C++ compilers that are capable of producing Windows executables - CLang, MingW, Cygwin, GCC, Watcom, Embarcadero, etc.